# Simple question of odds

Tags: probability

My wife and I are attending our annual Christmas party and we were told every employee has a 50% chance of winning a prize. Dozens of prizes are done by groups of tenure, but my wife and I are in the same group. So she's thinking our odds to win have doubled. I on the other hand think we would have had better odds IF we were not in the same tenure group.

Let's assume there are 4 groups with 50 employees in each group.

Who is correct? Me (2 50/50 chances at winning a single prize in 1 of 2 groups), or my wife (our combined odds at winning any prize in 1 group)?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "dozens of prizes are done by groups of tenure."

Comment: Can someone win more than one prize?

Comment: Also, I assume that nobody employee can win two prizes?

Comment: The "expected number of prizes" doesn't change (1).  If you stick together, there is a greater chance that you win exactly 1 prize and a smaller chance that you win 2 or 0.

Comment: Each group has the same number of prizes. No one can win more than once. Thanks guys!